# How to get center of camera position in Autodesk Forge?

Tags: autodesk-viewer, autodesk

How can I get the central position of the current camera in the viewer?

Answer (score 0):

The viewer camera can be obtained using [viewer.getCamera()](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#getcamera). The camera object itself uses the same interface as `THREE.Camera`, so you can get its properties the usual way, for example: `viewer.getCamera().position` will return a `THREE.Vector3` object with its position.

Comment: yes, i know, thanks, but i need to get the center position with actual camera behavior.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "central" or "center" position? If it's the "target" the camera is looking at, you can get that via `viewer.getCamera().target`, and if it's the point around which the camera is pivoting, it's `viewer.getCamera().pivot`.